# What is the complexity of first order logic?

Tags: first-order-logic

I would say that first-order-logic has a data complexity and a formula complexity.

Data complexity: fix the theory and let the structure vary and measure
complexity in the size of the domain of the structure. Complexity is exponential.

Formula complexity: fix the structure and let the formula vary and measure the complexity in the size of the formula. Complexity is exponential but because formulas are written by humans, it has probably an upperbound of 4 in real life.

EDIT: Try to explain better.

I follow an introductory course on FO logic. A question on the exam was: "What can you say about the complexity of FO in half a page?". The professor said it was a trick question.

I tried to identify a problem in first-order-logic with the highest complexity (a problem that I have seen in the class). Lets say FO finite model checking.

This problem has as input a finite structure S and a FO sentence e. Deciding whether S satisfies e is polynomial in the size of the domain of S and exponential in the size of e.

When measuring the complexity, we can fix the theory and let the structure vary and measure complexity in the size of the domain of the structure (data complexity).

Alternatively, we can fix the structure and let the formula vary and measure the complexity of the inference problem in the size of the formula. (formula complexity).

There are algorithms for finite model checking using relational algebra that are exponential in the number of quantifier alternations ∀∃∀∃. In practice, this number is always low. Probably an upperbound of 4.

Comment: What is your question? Both of your definitions are very vague, and when this is done formally it takes up huge space, since it involves describing computation (often through turingmachines). Also if you involve "What is often done by humans" in the complexity argument, it all becomes very weird, so try to keep that for a more philosophical question on computation. I would suggest reading up on this subject, for instance : Finite model theory, By Ebbinghaus and Flum, Chapter 7 about descriptive complexity.

Comment: I follow an introductory course on FO logic and an exam question was: "think about the complexity of FO logic and explain in a half page". The professor said it was a trick question. We used the book "logic in computer science" by Huth and Ryan. In the class, we covert FO, FO extensions with types and aggregates, modelling in FO, UNA, DCA, multiple inference problems such as evaluation inference, optimisation inference, finite model checking, .. .We also saw higher order logic.

Comment: I think there might be a really interesting question here, but currently it's too unclear. Can you explain what you mean by "data complexity" and "formula complexity" (in particular, can you give precise definitions of these terms)?

Answer (score 2):

I take the question to mean: what is the computational complexity of model-checking first-order logic over finite structures?

The combined complexity is PSPACE-complete (Theorem 4.3).

The data complexity is in ALOGTIME (Theorem 4.2, Corollary 4.5).

[Source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066104805383?via%3Dihub)

Comment: The data complexity is not in DLOGTIME. It is uniform $\mathrm{AC}^0$, i.e., alternating logarithmic time with a constant number of alternations.

Comment: Right, thanks for the correction. I've added the Theorem numbers to the citation.

Answer (score 0):

If the domain contains $n$ elements and the formula contains $m$ variables, then the truth table should be no larger than $n^m$. And if this is what you mean by this question, this would imply that your second statement makes sense and the first statement is under question.